# Change the img markup using custom image effect

Tags: media

I want to change the markup of all the images that are using my custom image effect which I've added using `hook_image_effect_info`.
I've added a callback function and I managed to to accomplish the above, altought the image dimentiones are NULL.
Why are the dimentions empty? Is there a better way to change the image markuup according to the image effect?